# Passing class to use instanceof in a function

Tags: java, instanceof

I have a class structure:

```
class BonusCard{
}

class AddResourceCard extends BonusCard{

}

class AddGoldCard extends BonusCard{

}
```

Now, I also have a function in which I want to pass AddResourceCard or AddGoldCard and in someones Inventory I want to check if an object in that Inventory is an instance of the class that I put into the function.

```
private void removeCardFromPlayer(Player player, BonusCard cardToRemove){
    for(BonusCard card : player.getInventory().getBonusCards()){
        if(card instanceof cardToRemove.getClass()){ //this line doesn't work sadly
            player.getInventory().getBonusCards().remove(card);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

A function call should look like this:

```
removeCardFromPlayer(player, AddResourceCard);
```

or

```
removeCardFromPlayer(player, AddGoldCard);
```

There should be an easy straightforward way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I just don't really know what to search for to be completely honest.

Comment: I would suggest not using classes for this, possibly consider an enum. That said. You need to include how you create the bonus card and how you create the cardToRemove.

Comment: Either make it `private void removeCardFromPlayer(Player player, Class<?>cardToRemoveClass)` or don't use instanceof but rather `card.getClass().equals(cardToRemove.getClass())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `card.getClass().equals(cardToRemove.getClass())`.

This compares the classes of the two objects and checks whether they are the same.
If you want to regard some hierarchy, you would then probably rather go for isAssignableFrom instead of equals

Comment: Glad to help. If you could accept the answer that would be great.

Comment: @DidseaJ I'm surprised that `card.getClass().equals(cardToRemove.getClass())` returns true, but `card instanceof cardToRemove.getClass()` returns false. It would be good if you could create a complete example.

Comment: @matt the `card instanceof cardToRemove.getClass()` doesn't return false, it's simply not supported by the language. You would have to put the class you are checking against explicitly.

Comment: Oh true, they just wrote "doesn't work", I didn't realize it was not compiling. so `.isInstance` would be a good replacement. I also think `isAssignableFrom` is even better since `equals` will miss subclass.

Comment: Actually, I had to edit it a little bit.
Christian's approach is perfectly fine for what I'm trying to accomplish, however the .equals method compares the entire object. What I did instead is the following:

 `if(card.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(cardToRemove.getClass().getSimpleName()))`

Calling my function, I just create an Object of the class that I want to remove and compare their names.

Comment: I think, `cardToRemove.getClass().isInstance( card);` is the most straight forward. If you subclass card you might have BonusCards that do not have the same simple name.

Comment: Good point @matt, I'm now using your suggested approach.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to pass the class itself:

```
private void removeCardFromPlayer(Player player, Class<? extends BonusCard> typeToRemove) {
    for (BonusCard card : player.getInventory().getBonusCards()) {
        if (typeToRemove.isInstance(card)) {
            player.getInventory().getBonusCards().remove(card);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Calls to the method would look like this:

```
removeCardFromPlayer(player, AddResourceCard.class);
removeCardFromPlayer(player, AddGoldCard.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add new abstract method `boolean canBeRemoved()` to the parent class. And override and implement it in the child classes.

Then in the loop, I just will call this method and act accordingly.